# Como acelerar a webview?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

Existe alguma maneira de acelerar o Carregamento de site via webview do Android? Vi que no meu aplicativo demora até 5 segundos pra carregar uma página, enquanto o navegador Chrome carrega em 1 segundo.

Comment: Já tentou carregar seu aplicativo no Chrome com todos os dados limpos? Você pode estar vendo o efeito do cache do navegador.

Comment: sim, no app realmente é mais lento pra abrir a página do site, no chrome é rápido.